# Get current url with query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How could I find (file) name with parameters of current page using C# in code behind? E.g with:

```
mysite.com/folder1/car.aspx?car_id=1&region=3
```

I want to get the string `car.aspx?car_id=1&region=3`

Comment: Are you using WebForms, Asp.Net-mvc, or Weg Pages?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I use Web forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

Also you can use this :

```
Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

Comment: A thank you, using `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` and `Substring` resolve my issue!